# LaTeX Rendering problem in firefox

Tags: bug, status-norepro

Not sure if it's just me but I've been having problems rendering some LaTeX in firefox.  For example this question: [Proof of Bochner formula/ Weitzenböck formula in a non-normal frame](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82112/proof-of-bochner-formula-weitzenbock-formula-in-a-non-normal-frame) .  It does however render correctly in chrome.  Here is what it looks like in firefox:
[image]

Comment: I'm using Firefox, and do not have any problem (as of right now) with the display of that equation.

Comment: What Arturo said. Try clearing your cache?

Comment: Also, which version of Firefox? Are you on FF 8 already? I am still on 7...

Comment: Also looks good here in FF8.

Comment: im on firefox 7.  i've also tried clearing my cache.

Answer (score 2):

We can't duplicate this.

Many Firefox problems can be solved by running in Firefox Safe Mode, which disables extensions.

http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Safe%20Mode

> At the top of the Firefox window, click the Firefox button, go over to the Help menu and select Restart with Add-ons Disabled.... Firefox will start up with the Firefox Safe Mode dialog.
>
> For Windows XP, click the Help menu and select Restart with Add-ons Disabled....