# Latex not rendered on FF 8.0 under Windows 7 (and editing bugs)

Tags: bug, status-norepro, mathjax

All new to this site. From the start, Latex is rendered as typed, not translated into mathematical typesetting. I realize there are duplicate question, eg

[LaTeX Rendering problem in firefox](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3217/latex-rendering-problem-in-firefox)

but I couldn't find any that actually seemed to resolve the issue. Ideas or suggestions?

Edit: as I found out through the below comments and answers, there are apparently other issues I am aware of to be broken: editing is limited as described in my comment below. I uploaded the image from my Ubuntu machine, in which I also see, and can use, the editing buttons; and in which Latex is rendered fine.

[image: (example screenshot)]

Comment: What OS are you on? Can you take a screenshot of what the site looks like from your end?

Comment: For this problem, Windows 7. I'm blanking on how to attach a screenshot (it's taken but I don't seem to see where or how to attach it to the post). Imagine it really Latex as typed while editing a Latex file (I attach screen shot if someone could kindly advise how to).

Comment: When you edit your question, you should see an array of buttons above the text box. Click the sixth button from the left and follow the instructions.

Comment: I don't have those buttons either it seems. From bottom to top, I see, when editing: text box; space (about twice the size of title box); title box; header line "Questions Tags...".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can't duplicate this.

Many Firefox problems can be solved by running in Firefox Safe Mode, which disables extensions.

http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Safe%20Mode

> At the top of the Firefox window, click the Firefox button, go over to the Help menu and select Restart with Add-ons Disabled.... Firefox will start up with the Firefox Safe Mode dialog.
>
> For Windows XP, click the Help menu and select Restart with Add-ons Disabled....

Comment: Thanks for trying. It also appears somewhat randomly. I just checked again when seeing your answer, and it rendered fine. As I've only seen this under Windows 7, I have to assume it's some instability in that kernel.